# How to generate solidity encode function signature from Javascript?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, javascript, ethereumjs

What I am trying to achieve is like , i should be able to call a set of solidity functions dynamically based on some criteria. i'm using call() method to achieve the same.

```
(bool success, bytes memory result) =APContract.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(string(data), "hello"));
```

`data` variable contain the function call string "testCall(string)".  instead of encoding from the contract I should be able to encode the same with javascript (because of some argument generation logic). so that i can call the function like `APContract.call(data)`. Is there any method that help to achieve the same?

Comment: Just clarification: What i wanted is javascript snipet equivalent to `abi.encodeWithSignature("testCall(string)", "hello")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I used to crack the [Ethernaut Puzzle Wallet level](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe13a4a46C346154C41360AAe7f070943F67743c9). I believe `encodeFunctionCall` is exactly what you're looking for:

```
let deposit   = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(contract.abi[2], [])
let multicall = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(contract.abi[6], [[deposit]])
let calldata  = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(contract.abi[6], [[deposit, multicall]])

await sendTransaction({
  from:  player, 
  to:    instance,
  value: web3.utils.toWei('0.001', "ether"),
  data:  calldata
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understood your question but you can take a look at the Solidity Documentation Contract ABI Specification: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#examples

To see how to encode the parameters on your own. It is basically a big concatenated strings set of function name hash and function arguments.

You can also take a look at this lib which performs "custom contract calls" (so not relying on any ABI): https://github.com/ERC725Alliance/erc725.js/blob/main/src/lib/utils.ts

#### Manual way

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3();

const methodId = web3.utils.keccak256('testCall(string)').substr(0, 10); //0xc7cee1b7

// In this function call, the first and only parameter uses a dynamic type: string
// https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types

// we use the offset in bytes to the start of their data area, measured from the start of the value encoding
// offset to start of data part of second parameter, 1*32 bytes, exactly the size of the head part

const stringArgument = web3.utils.padLeft(web3.utils.toHex(1*32), 64).replace('0x', '');
// 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020


const stringValue = 'TODO' // This one is a bit tricky, the docs explain it well: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types

const call = methodId + stringArgument + stringValue;
```

#### ABI way

You can always construct your own ABI dict, then web3 will handle the above conversion for you:

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        [
            {
                name: 'testCall',
                inputs: [
                    { type: 'bytes32', name: '_hash', internalType: 'bytes32' },
                ],
            },
        ],
        contractAddress,
    );

const answer = await contract.methods
            .testCall(messageHash)
            .call();
```

#### ABI utils way

Use the helpers fonctions from: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth-abi.html to build what you need.

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('string', 'Hello')
```

Edit: you can also check [web3 source code](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/1.x/packages/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js)

Comment: Thanks for putting effort on answering.what i wanted to do is encode the method from javascript using a method equivalent to`abi.encodeWithSignature("testCall(string)", "hello")`. and the encoded bytes will be passed a parameter of a solidity function (will be web3 call). that particular function will call like `aPContract.call(data)`. `data` is the encoded bytes came as argument of the called function. It'll be help full if you guide in that way